# Worklight Console set "Active, Notifying" to push notification to client.

Tags: notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I use worklight5.06 Console set "Active, Notifying" to push notification and my App can receive that. But same setting in worklight6.20, my APP not receive the notification.

What's difference in WL5.06 and WL6.20?

I'm follow the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDHrqnWieXI

Below is my APP code:

```
    <body onload="WL.Client.init({})" style="display: none;">
        <!--application UI goes here-->
        Hello Worklight
        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything's changed between 5.0.6 and 6.2. Note that even 6.2 is old, as there is no 7.1. You really should upgrade.

You can read the What's New section of 6.2 (and I recommend reading that of 6.1 and 6.0 as well), in the Knowledge Center: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html

More specifically the whole way you are initializing your application in that code snippet is *wrong*.

Please create a new project and application in Worklight Studio 6.2 and take a look at the project structure and the way it works.

Easiest to make sure that Remote Notifying is working for you is by adding the connect API, and then setting in the console the notification. Finally, to verify, launch the app either in preview or device.

Do not change the HTML. *Only* replace `wlCommonInit()` in main.js with the following:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: success, onFailure: failure});
}

function success() {
    alert ("success");
}

function failure() {
    alert ("failure");
}
```

When testing, you should get an alert showing "connect" followed by another alert with the remote notify text you've placed in the console.

Note: unlike with 5.0.6 you do not need to edit application-descriptor.xml with the server URL. This is done for you in the development environment by Studio.

Comment: Thanks Idan. I changed the server IP from localhost to IP, then  I can receive the notification.